# Connected callback is not being called while creating custom html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I was trying to create a custom tag in HTML using JavaScript. I want to create the custom element using ES6 JavaScript syntax. I have written this code to create the custom element:

```js
customElements.define('neo-element', NeoElement);
function NeoElement (){
    var ref =  Reflect.construct(HTMLElement,[], this.constructor) ;
    return ref;
};
NeoElement.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
NeoElement.prototype.constructor = NeoElement;
NeoElement.prototype.connectedCallback = function(){
    this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello world</h1>`;
};
```

```html
<neo-element></neo-element>
```

I have verified that NeoElement is extending HTMLElement properly, but still nothing is getting printed inside the `<neo-element>` tag.

Could anyone look at the code and tell me what am I missing in ES5 syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're calling `customElements.define`—and thereby upgrading your `<neo-element>` to an instance of NeoElement—before you've defined `NeoElement.prototype`, `NeoElement.prototype.constructor`, and `NeoElement.prototype.connectedCallback`.

If you move `customElements.define` to the end it works fine:

```js
function NeoElement() {
    var ref = Reflect.construct(HTMLElement,[], this.constructor) ;
    return ref;
};
NeoElement.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
NeoElement.prototype.constructor = NeoElement;
NeoElement.prototype.connectedCallback = function(){
    this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello world</h1>`;
};
customElements.define('neo-element', NeoElement);
```

```html
<neo-element></neo-element>
```

Comment: Thank you. I worked when I moved the `customElements.define('neo-element', NeoElement)` at the end.

I thought that sequence wont matter when we define anything with prototypes. But here, it broke the flow.

Comment: @NPrafull In JavaScript function declarations (i.e. `function someFn() { ... }`) are [hoisted](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript), but property assignments (`someFn.myProp = ...`) are not. Assigning to `prototype` isn't special in that regard—it's just a regular property assignment—so it didn't happen until after `customElements.define`.